# Python count lines with numbers less than, or more than

Tags: python

I'm new to python and writing a program to count lines. the file looks like this:

```
  0.86149806
  1.8628227
 -0.1380086
 -1
  0.99927421
 -1.0007207
  0.99927421
  0.99926955
  -1.0007258
```

And my code attempt is the following:

```
counterPos = 0
counterNeg = 0
counterTot = 0
counterNeu = 0
with open('test.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        counterTot += 1
        for i in line:
            if i > 0.3:
                counterPos += 1
            elif i < -0.3:
                counterNeg += 1
            else:
                counterNeu += 1
```

I'm trying to get it to count all lines lower than -0.3 to `counterNeg`, all lines above 0.3 as `counterPos`, and all lines that have a number between 0.29 and -0.29 to `counterNeu`.

It doesn't seem to work though, I know im going wrong with `for i in line` but not sure how.

Comment: What about numbers between 0.29 and 0.3 (and between -0.3 and -0.29)?

Comment: hmm how would i fix that?

Comment: @abarnert Numbers between 0.29 and 0.3 just increase `counterNeu` by one, don't they? both `0.29 > 0.3` and `0.29 < -0.3` are false, so the `else:` chunk is executed.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: That's what the _code_ does, but that's not what his description asked for. So, if it's what he wants, he's done; if it's not what he wants, it's a bug in his code.

Comment: @RHK-S8: It depends on what you want to happen with those numbers. Do you want them to increment `counterNeu`? (In that case you're done.) Increment nothing? Increment `counterPos` and `counterNeu` by 0.5 each? Something else?

Comment: well i think everything above and below 0.3 and -0.3 should work fine as they do

Comment: I thought that was just a joke about those numbers, as the OP wasn't precise enough in his question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `line` is a string, but you want to parse it as a `float`. Just use `float(line)`.

It's also better to strip all whitespace from the beginning and end of your line just in case. So:

```
for line in infile:
    i = float(line.strip())
    # ... count
```

Comment: Getting accepted, you should at least mention the extra loop.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen I'm sorry, what extra loop are you talking about?

Comment: `for line in infile: for i in line:` He's looping through every character on each line.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen He said that he realises that it is not correct. You think it is possible to keep that extra loop with the code I provided?

Comment: I know it's not possible to keep that extra loop, which is why you should mention that he should remove it, geez.

Answer (score 3):

You are using one extra loop.
Also the data read from the files comes as str with "\n" as endline char. Use strip() to remove "\n" and then convert the data as float.

End code should be like:

```
counterPos = 0
counterNeg = 0
counterTot = 0
counterNeu = 0
with open('temp.txt', 'r') as infile:
        counterTot += 1
        for i in infile:            
                if float(i.strip()) > 0.3:
                    counterPos += 1
                elif float(i.strip()) < -0.3:
                    counterNeg += 1
                else:
                    counterNeu += 1
```

Answer (score -1):

When I find myself doing a lot of tests, I usually do something along these lines:

```
data='''\
  0.86149806
  1.8628227
 -0.1380086
 -1
  0.99927421
 -1.0007207
  0.99927421
  0.99926955
  -1.0007258'''

def f1(x):
    ''' >0.3 '''
    return x>0.3

def f2(x):
    ''' <-0.3 '''   
    return x<-.3

def f3(x):
    ''' not f1 and not f2 '''   
    return not f1(x) and not f2(x)

tests={f1: 0,
       f2: 0,
       f3: 0 }

for line in data.splitlines():
    for test in tests:
        if test(float(line.strip())): 
            tests[test]+=1

for f,v in sorted(tests.items()):
    print '{:3}{:20}:{}'.format(f.__name__, f.__doc__, v)
```

Prints:

```
f1  >0.3               :5
f2  <-0.3              :3
f3  not f1 and not f2  :1
```

Comment: Considering he's not yet too advanced at python (according to the original post), I can't see how is this helping him or answering his question. It's the same as if he asked how to build a wheel, and you'd teach him how to build a car.

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to talk in programming 'baby talk' to novices. Using a dict mapping rather than a bunch of individual variables is a core Python idiom.